# contar en una tabla con condicionales

Tags: sql

Quiero contar los que son solo 0, los que son solo 9 y los que tienen 0 y 9. El tema es que no me genera el OR exclusivo.

```
select count(distinct (cuit_nu))    
from p_dw_explo.cpd_mensual as a
left join p_dw_explo.ch_cheque_cartera as b on (a.nro_boleta_nu = b.CHBC_Nro_Boleta and a.operacion_tx=b.LOAN_Nro_Oper and a.importe_vl= b.CHCC_Imp_Cheque and a.nro_ch_nu=b.CHCC_Nro_Cheque)
where proc_fc>= date '2020-06-01' and b.ch_instrumento_cod = 9 and b.ch_instrumento_cod <> 0.
```

Comment: Bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow en español, mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funciona el sitio y de paso obtener tu primera medalla. Por favor indica qué motor de base de datos estas usando y qué valores tiene la tabla para entender mejor la pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: Las bases de datos no tienen or exclusivo, porque analizan cada fila por separado contra todas las condiciones.. por lo tanto, siempre te va a dar true ese set de condiciones.. esto lo podes hacer con un case trayendo solo los que son 0 y 9, y analizando ahi cada caso...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacer lo que buscas, en primer lugar deberías llevar la condición que el valor de `ch_instrumento_cod` es 1 o 9 a nivel de fila, y sobre eso podrías contar cada caso:

```
select count(case when es0 = 1 and es9 = 0 then 1 else null end) as solo0,
       count(case when es0 = 0 and es9 = 1 then 1 else null end) as solo9,
       count(case when es0 = 1 and es9 = 1 then 1 else null end) as ambos
       from (select cuit_nu, 
                    max(case when b.ch_instrumento_cod = 0 then 1 else null end) es0,
                    max(case when b.ch_instrumento_cod = 9 then 1 else null end) es9
                    from p_dw_explo.cpd_mensual as a
                    left join p_dw_explo.ch_cheque_cartera as b 
                       on (a.nro_boleta_nu = b.CHBC_Nro_Boleta and 
                           a.operacion_tx=b.LOAN_Nro_Oper and 
                           a.importe_vl= b.CHCC_Imp_Cheque and 
                           a.nro_ch_nu=b.CHCC_Nro_Cheque)
                    where proc_fc>= date '2020-06-01' 
                          and b.ch_instrumento_cod in (0, 9)
                    group by cuit_nu
        )
```